# Display none to display inline in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, position, fixed

I have taken a look at others and added my doctype but it still doesn't work

I am building a website where you click on a product and a div opens with more info, that part was no problem with firefox, Chrome, etc. but IE of course doesn't even show the div.

so this is what I have

```
#div{position:fixed; display:none;}
```

now when I click the item the code changes to

```
#div{position:fixed; display:inline;}
```

IE isn't displaying the div at all though.

This website is going to be up and running in February so I need help please!
Hopefully it's nothing too hard...

Also I don't want to use jQuery... at all just HTML CSS and Javascript

Thank you!

update: 
Thank you for showing me my mistake but I did put display:none; in my code it was just a mistake on here.

update 2:

Here is my javascript

```
function view ()
{
screen.style.display = "block";
title.innerHTML = "<h1>" + set[0] + "</h1>";
purchase.innerHTML = set[0] + " costs " + set[1];
images.innerHTML = "<center>" + set[3] + set[2] + "</center>";
}
```

and this is my CSS

```
#screen{background-color:yellow; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:780px; height:400px; z-index:4; display:none;}
```

and this is my HTML

```
<div id="screen">

<div id="title">
</div>
<div id="images">
</div>
<div id="purchase">
</div>
```

I removed the text inside the div as that is not important. 
Again this works perfect in all browsers except in IE

Comment: why position fixed? try removing that just to test IE. besides, there is no display:hidden, there is display:none

Comment: Do you know how many versions of IE are out there? specify a version[s]. Maybe make a jsfiddle.net to show you issue. Show the code that dos the switching!

Comment: When you say "the code changes", what does it mean exactly? are you using classes?

Comment: Would you please add the line(s) of JavaScript you use to change to switch the classes?

Comment: Yes that was a mistake but my code says display:none;

Answer (score 0):

You mean either this:
`display:hidden` isn't a valid option.

```
#div {
  position:fixed;
  display:none;   /* Hide it entirely */
}
```

Or this:

```
#div {
  position:fixed;
  visibility: hidden    /* Don't display, but reserve the space for it */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline` is not a valid option for a div, which is a block element. You should use "block", "inline-block", or just leave the property empty to get the default.

`display: hidden;` is not valid either, I believe you mean `display: none;`

[Update] Looking at your code, it might be because you are using reserved words as variable names. Instead of "screen" or "title" for example, try to call your variables "myScreen" and "myTitle".

Here is a list of reserved words:

http://mattsnider.com/reserved-words-in-javascript/

P.S.: as others pointed out, for such questions it would be helpful to specify in which version(s) of IE you did the tests.

Comment: That was a mistake, my code is display:none; and I tried block but it didn't work. Thank you for your help though I really wish I could figure this out

Comment: ok. Note that you didn't answer the comments asking for more details on your code.

Comment: Thank you so much the update helped a lot I didn't even think about reserved words haha but this worked perfectly thank you! =]